# The resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I made a really simple MVC application with VS 2010 beta. just a view with 2 fields ID, and name made the controller and just tried to check the Index page. I am getting the following error. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.21006; ASP.NET Version:4.0.21006.1 
i am running on my laptop Windows 7 Home Premium I installed also IIS 7. is there some special option in order to work with MVC2. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually after your post i checked my code and since I am asp.net developer I had set a view as starting page and by typing F5 I was going to http://localhost/Views/Mypage.aspx. it has been fixed, but I have another question how to start with a different controller than home? thanks again, and I am learning MVC and start liking. with few lines of code you get a page with a list of your model, with link to update, new, details etc. Now i have to add paging, sort, etc. Thaks again

Comment: By default you MVC application hits home controller, one workaround is redirect from that home controller to some other controller from where you want to start.

Comment: or you can edit your routes in global.ascx to have some other controller as default in your default route. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible that your routes are causing the problem.

If you could post your Global.asax, your controller and the url your are trying to access, then it would be helpful to answer more accurately.

Thanks